# Replicate tab Panel in GUI Builder google apps

Tags: google-apps-script

I think I've seen this answer, but I can't remember where for certain.

I'm trying to to create a tabbed panel interface using the GUI Builder, but don't see that option. The part I seem to recall is someone having an approach to replicate that in the GUI Builder.  I just can't seem to find that information in my brain, the old google groups or here.

Can someone jog my memory?

Thank you...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the final functionality you're looking for ? There has been a post where it was asked how to have 2 UIs in the same UI and a way to switch between them 'just as if it were tabs'... is that what you want ?

Comment: Once again Serge, you've read my mind :)  After reading your message I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100349/what-is-he-best-way-to-manage-two-ui).  Is that the one you are referring to?

Comment: Ideally I'll have 4 panels to start with.  1 -login 2-import from external system 3-export to csv 4-User options.

Comment: funny, I didn't see your link while answering !!! it was indeed the same post ;-D

Comment: Hi Joe, test script is on line and in EDIT, as a starting point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the post you were referring to was [this one ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100349/what-is-he-best-way-to-manage-two-ui/11100836#11100836) Anyway, no matter how much panels you have, yo could design them in the GUI, one on top of the other or (more simply) one under each other in a 'parent' vertical panel and play with client handlers to show/hide the one you need.
I have an example [here with 2 panels in an UI](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/a-database-project/a-label-printing-tool), the UI is designed with script but that is not important, look at the client handlers to see how it works.

If I have some free time tonight I'll make a demo script for 4 panels in GUI ;-).

EDIT : here is [a test example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxlPTVLSLfO3d1w2vSrMzzh57p9DJM6ivCIHiIfTB2AKqubSs1L/exec) (standalone) or [embedded in a Google site](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/multipanel-ui) + [link to the script](https://script.google.com/d/10BW-J2rMmnQS3770XrpkHx_fwofzsL9tiDNohn4vBHlK5dYbdQTNGK0E/edit) (make a copy to edit)

*Note that in the GUI builder you'l have to 'play' with visibility of each panel to work on it, I used a main panel large enough to hold 2 panels together so you can have a better vision of "harmony" between panels (which is not the case in my test;-))*

and the code (very simple basic example 4 panels with each of them a textBox & a Label, just to test the handlers on the buttons):

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var UI=app.loadComponent('multiUi')

  var panel1 = app.getElementById('panel1')
  var panel2 = app.getElementById('panel2')
  var panel3 = app.getElementById('panel3')
  var panel4 = app.getElementById('panel4')

  var Button1 = app.getElementById('Button1')
  var Button2 = app.getElementById('Button2')
  var Button3 = app.getElementById('Button3')
  var Button4 = app.getElementById('Button4')

  var pHandler1 = app.createClientHandler()
  .forTargets(panel1).setVisible(true).forTargets(panel2,panel3,panel4).setVisible(false)
  Button1.addClickHandler(pHandler1)

  var pHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .forTargets(panel2).setVisible(true).forTargets(panel1,panel3,panel4).setVisible(false)
  Button2.addClickHandler(pHandler2)

  var pHandler3 = app.createClientHandler()
  .forTargets(panel3).setVisible(true).forTargets(panel2,panel1,panel4).setVisible(false)
  Button3.addClickHandler(pHandler3)

  var pHandler4 = app.createClientHandler()
  .forTargets(panel4).setVisible(true).forTargets(panel2,panel3,panel1).setVisible(false)
  Button4.addClickHandler(pHandler4)

  app.add(UI)
  return app;
}
```

Comment: That is great stuff!
With the Panels 'inside' the Vertical Panel, it that how the Panels 'rise' up to the top when they become visible?

I've kept my apps pretty simple but am looking to do a little more.. You're help has (as usual) been fantastic!

Comment: Serge, I took your example, tweaked it a bit as a POC for some folks. Our eventual goal is to embed something like this in a Google Site Page.  (Here's where my memory fails again).  I looked here [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436448/the-url-is-not-recognized-as-a-valid-google-script/11437403#11437403  and saw that some issues may arise when trying to embed. Are you able to embed yours in a GSite? Or will I need to use a hyperlink (as in your post above) for delivery?

Comment: If you want to insert a standalone script in an iframe you'll have to re-design the url like this `https://sites.google.com/macros/exec?service=key...`, taking the key from the "normal" url you use in a browser window. I tested it on my site and it works as expected. PS : happy to hear that it was useful to you ;-)  the vertical panel is indeed what helps to keep everything in place.

Comment: Example [on this link](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/multipanel-ui) and I also modified a bit the elements of the UI with colors and removed some borders... at least it's a bit more fun now ;-)

Comment: I had to thank you for throwing this idea !! I'm going to use it in a webbapp I'm working on right now and this 'tab' trick is really looking nice. If you feel like [giving it a peek](https://script.google.com/a/macros/insas.be/s/AKfycby1CQyMYZslTV4lRfjjLNWXiDIr2REiyV8PS3xfQ7ORFW5ONpti/exec)... (work in progress, only one panel is ready, others are still empty but not for long ;-)

Comment: That code has a line: `var UI=app.loadComponent('multiUi')`  I guess the `multiUi` is a file out on the internet somewhere?  If I copy the file, it runs.  If I copy and paste the code, it doesn't run.  I have no idea what is in that `multiUi` file or where it comes from.  And I don't know how to make my own.

Comment: This example was built using the so called GUI builder which is deprecated. It is still working but there is no way to create it anymore. As you can see, this post was written in 2012 :-) .

Answer (score 0):

The following code makes the tabs, based on the array you put in, dynamically:

```
function doGet() {
    // create application
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();

    // set array
    var aTabs = ['donald','katrijn','dagobert'];                                                         

    // create tab panel
    var pTab = app.createTabPanel();                                                

    // add tabs to panel
    for(var k=0; k<pTabs.length; k++) {
      pTab.add(app.createLabel("This tab is reserved for " +  aTabs[k]), aTabs[k]);
    } 

    // add panel to application 
    app.add(pTab); 

    // set focus to first tab                                                                                     
    pTab.selectTab(0);                                                                                   

    // return to application
    return app;
}
```

See [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tabpanel) for tabPanel reference.

Publishing your script as a web-app, allows you to insert the script on a google sites.