# Hide a component shown by loadComponent

Tags: google-apps-script

I am loading a component in doGet, and after a click event I am trying to hide that component and show another.  *These were made in GUI Builder.*  First of all, is it even possible to have 2 different components?  If so, how can I get the 2nd component to show up on top of the other?  Here is my code:

```
function doGet() {
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  app.add(app.loadComponent("first", {"z-index": "1"}));

  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

   var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
   label.setVisible(true);

   app.close();
   return app;
}

function afterClick(){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.add(app.loadComponent("second", {"z-index": "100"}));

 return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have 2 components in the GUI builder, please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661146/replicate-tab-panel-in-gui-builder-google-apps) that offers a solution for multiple UI using GUI builder . This option will be smoother as the UI actually doesn't close between each panel showup.

To adapt this approach to your code don't forget you can assign multiple handlers to the same widget, for example a client handler to switch visibility and a server handler to call your function. Both will fire together...