# UiApp cache vertical panel

Tags: google-apps-script

Developing small app to record a set of 6 readings for monitoring purposes in 31 rooms. App will have two main views, one view to show list of buttons for each room where readings will be taken, a second view where the values will be entered for a particular room and then posted to a spreadsheet.

The process in mind here is click on button for a particular room, enter the data, return to button view to choose another room to enter the data for that room and then back to button view screen.

Since the button view will seldom change do I have any options for caching this view so that I do not have to run a function to rebuild it each time. I have this function

```
function createTGSRoomListButtons(sh, aData){}
```

That takes the list of rooms and builds a panel of buttons for selecting the different rooms.

The question that I have can the above function be run once to cobble together the UI, cached and the later simply be 'recalled'?

TO that some end the view where the data will be entered can this be partially cached so that with each rendering a reference to a specific room can be made.

New to Google Apps Script so not really sure how to properly determine my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple panels in an UI and play with visibility to show one or another... no need to cache any content since they remain unchanged in the process.
If I understood your use case well, the panel with specific room info would be modified according to spreadsheet data so in this case you won't need to cache values since they would be "reconstructed" each time. The trick to show/hide panel has been shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661146/replicate-tab-panel-in-gui-builder-google-apps) with clientHandlersand multiple panels in a unique vertical panel to ensure that the visible panel is always at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way would be build the UI for the first time and then hide/unhide the buttons' panel each time using the setVisible() method of the panel